# How to do for loop through all items of a list except the first

Tags: python, loops, for-loop

Imagine I have a list of balls objects as follows:

```
balls = [container,ball1,ball2,ball3,ball4]
```

I want to do a for loop that will go through ball1, ball2, ball3, ball4 but not the first item container.

What is a method for doing it?

Comment: There are multiple ways you can achieve this, I think why your question has been downvoted is that it looks you have not done any research.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [list slices](https://docs.python.org/3.6/tutorial/introduction.html#lists):

```
for i in balls[1:]:
    print(i)
```